# (Scrapy, , django, python) ImportError: No module named settings

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I know that this question was already asked, but I didn't find a solution. I am trying to follow a tutorial about integrating a Scrapy project in a django app. When I try to run "scrapy crawl particip" it gives me an import error about (django) settings. This is my folder tree:

```
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── mappingsite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── storedirectoryscraper
│   ├── scrapy.cfg
│   └── storedirectoryscraper
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── items.py
│       ├── pipelines.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── settings.pyc
│       └── spiders
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── particip.py
└── storemapapp
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

The relevant code in storedirectoryscraper.settings file (Scrapy settings):

```
sys.path.append('<abs path to BloggerWorkspace/mappingsite>')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mappingsite.settings'

django.setup()


BOT_NAME = 'storedirectoryscraper'
```

How shoulld be defined the right path to the file and why?

[EDIT]

my error traceback:

```
(BloggerWorkspace) popovvasile@popovvasile:~/work/BloggerWorkspace/mappingsite/storedirectoryscraper$ scrapy crawl particip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 282, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/popovvasile/work/BloggerWorkspace/mappingsite/storedirectoryscraper/storedirectoryscraper/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named mappingsite.settings
```

Comment: You're appending one directory too deep to `sys.path`.  `mappingsite` is already present in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`; it should not also be in `sys.path`.

Comment: I removed mappingsite from sys.path. Still doesn't work.

Comment: The whole project is located in a map which is also named mappingsite (more exactly in BloggerWorkspace/mappingsite), so the previous settings make sens.

Comment: Show us the exact command you're running, and the full error traceback.

Comment: Ok, I added it to the question.